# Creating a UIWebView programmatically w/delegates

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4

I'm creating a UIWebView programmatically but I need to have this function fire so hrefs open in a custom view:

```
-(bool) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{

    //You might need to set up a interceptLinks-Bool since you don't want to intercept the initial loading of the content
    if (interceptLinks) {
        NSURL *url = request.URL;
        //This launches your custom ViewController, replace it with your initialization-code
        BrowserViewController *bv = [[BrowserViewController alloc] initWithUrl:url];
        bv.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
        [self presentModalViewController:bv animated:YES];
        [bv release];
         return NO;
    }
    //No need to intercept the initial request to fill the WebView
    else {
        interceptLinks = YES;
        return YES;
    }
}
```

How do I link delegates to a UIWebView created programmactically so the functions will fire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing above looks correct.

Just add UIWebViewDelegate protocol on your interface class, and on your implementation class
add

```
webview.delegate = self;
```

So your shouldStartLoadWithRequest is called.

Comment: I added this to my interface class: @interface TestNib : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>, then i added self.webView = self; to the implementation, but i get a warning which most likely is an error, incompatible pointer types. What am i doing wrong

Comment: sorry, made a correction above. should be webView.delegate = self;

Comment: still didnt call it. heres a link to the project. Maybe seeing the entire code will help. http://troycomptonworld.com/error/htmldecoder.zip

Comment: You should add webView.delegate = self; only after initializing the webView. So move it below the webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 48)]; line

Comment: and also correct method signature has BOOL (capital letters instead of bool). Otherwise you will get compile time warnings - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {  NSLog(@"inside shouldStartLoad");
    return YES;
}

Answer (score 1):

I've just checked your code and the answer is obvious :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    webView.delegate = self;
    webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 48)];

    NSString *html = @"<html><body><a href=""http://yahoo.com"">Yahoo</a></body></html>";  
    [webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.hitchhiker.com/message"]]; 
    [self.view addSubview:webView];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Your are setting the delegate on something not yet initialized ! Just set the delegate after the alloc/init and it will work !

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 48)];
    webView.delegate = self;
    ...
}
```

You should also replace the lower case "bool" to "BOOL" in this :

```
-(bool) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

(it is not the root problem, it's just to remove a warning ...)

Answer (score 0):

```
[myWebView setDelegate:self]; // if the controller implements the delegate
```

Comment: I added this code in the viewDidLoad method, but the function still wasnt called

Comment: just to be sure - do you actually implement the delegate - like in

@interface YourViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>

Comment: i did...hers a link to my project. Maybe seeing the entire code will help. http://troycomptonworld.com/error/htmldecoder.zip